# Center words in Label which is in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uilabel

I want to center the text of a label which is in a collection view. I was looking inside the storyboard label settings and couldn't find a way to do it.  My code is

```
class SingleRowCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var tImageView: PFImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }}
```

Is this done by code or from the storyboard? When I build the app the words in the label come from the left and want it to be aligned to the center.

Comment: Try `tLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center`

Comment: yes I get a error saying expected declaration.

Comment: Where did you put it?

Comment: put it below `super.awakeFromNib()`

Comment: sorry not error I put it under awakefromNIB and doesn't work

Comment: yes I also did that and didn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84290/discussion-between-frequencymatched-and-satsuki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `layoutSubviews()`

```
class SingleRowCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var tImageView: PFImageView!
   @IBOutlet weak var tLabel: UILabel!
   override func layoutSubviews() {
      super.layoutSubviews()
      tLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
   }

   override func awakeFromNib() {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code
   }
 }
```